# Are there any natural occurrences of taking a trig function of a trig function?

Tags: trigonometry

In devising challenging exercises for my students, I am tempted to give them something like $\cos(3\sin(4))$, but then I get to wondering whether such a calculation would ever be encountered in practice. Since radians are dimensionless, as are values returned by trig functions, there is no mathematical barrier to this happening, but I was wondering if it ever happened naturally in the course of solving some problem, in mathematics, physics, finance, or elsewhere.

Comment: [This](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1949-8594.1945.tb06335.x) might be of interest.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This does occur. A notable example would be the Bessel function
$$J_n(x) = {1 \over \pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(nt - x\sin t)\,dt$$
These functions come up in various places in physics and so on. Also, whenever you do a contour integral such as ${\displaystyle \int_{|z| = 1}{1 \over \cos(z)}\,dz}$, if you parameterize the unit circle by $t \rightarrow e^{it}$ you will be doing the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}{ie^{it} \over \sin(e^{it})}\,dt$$
Due to Euler's formula the denominator is effectively the composition of trigonometric functions. And contour integrals of such functions come up in applications all the time.

Comment: Tiny note: the first integral representation given coincides with a Bessel function only for integer $n$. For general $n$, the function is called an [Anger function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10). There is also the related Weber function, where the $\cos$ is replaced by $\sin$.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks. That's a great addendum.

Answer (score 12):

This occurs naturally when you express a plane wave $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\mathbf k\mathbf x}$ in terms of the angle $\theta$ between $\mathbf k$ and $\mathbf x$ as $\mathrm e^{\mathrm ikx\cos\theta}=\cos(kx\cos\theta)+\mathrm i\sin(kx\cos\theta)$. This is especially relevant when expanding plane waves in terms of [cylindrical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) or [spherical](http://homer.phys.uh.edu/~hunger/class/fall_2008/lectures/lecture_6.pdf) waves, which is related to [scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_length) and the [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Properties) mentioned by Zarrax.

Answer (score 1):

[Phase modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_modulation) would come close.

Comment: I took a glance at the link. It looks tangential, but I appreciate the info.

Comment: The connection is most clear if you view the signal as a sum of pure tones (via Fourier analysis).